# Why is tikz-euclide adding a line/mark to each angle arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am drawing a triangle and its angles but tikz adds a small line to each arc of each angle. This should not happen as can be seen for example [here](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=1scb). My code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-1,2);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](A,O,B);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.25](A,O,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm](B,A,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](B,A,O){$\alpha$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7cm](O,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](O,B,A){$\beta$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

How can I draw an arc for an angle without a small line?

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Comment: You might want to list package versions as well (both on your own system and that online editor that I've never heard of). You can list versions by adding `\listfiles` before `\documentclass `, then they are listed in the log

Comment: Hey Matt, I closed your question as a duplicate under suggestion of other users, because I feel you were asking more or less the same. Let me/us know if the other question helps you with this one. :)

Answer (score 2):

With the new version `3.0` of tkz-euclide, by default, the macro `\tkzMarkAngle` marks the angle with a mark formed by a single small line.
To remove it, add the option `mark=none`.

```
\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5,mark=none](A,O,B);
```

To modify it, you have the choice with these options `|, ||,|||, z, s, x, o, oo`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-1,2);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5,mark=none](A,O,B);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.25](A,O,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,mark=none](B,A,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](B,A,O){$\alpha$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.7cm,mark=none](O,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](O,B,A){$\beta$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Example of other mark :  `|, ||,|||, z, s, x, o, oo`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (-1,2);
\draw (O)--(A)--(B)--cycle;

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5,mark=o](A,O,B);
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.25](A,O,B){$\gamma$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=1cm,mark=x](B,A,O)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](B,A,O){$\alpha$}

\tkzMarkAngle[size=0.8cm,mark=||](O,B,A)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.5](O,B,A){$\beta$}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```